# how to execute job postgresql on linux with dynamic name

Tags: sql, postgresql, scheduler

I have sql query below:

```
copy epolicy.table1(sequence_number, gsm_number_phone, sms_message, trans_date, trans_time, am_or_pm, entity, devision, id) 
from '/file/myfile_20180220.csv' delimiter U&'\0009' csv;
```

this sql running well but I not yet found the reference for run this sql with dynamic name, for example: the name should myfile_yyyymmddhhss. how to run this sql script, in my case with postgresql, with schedule? I not yet found the reference run this sql with cron job. any solution without install the apps or other? or you can give me the reference. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

lets say you have a table c:

```
t=# create table c(i int);
CREATE TABLE
```

now exit `psql` and create a file with dynamic name:

```
t=# \q
-bash-4.2$ echo '42' > /tmp/$(date --iso-8601).csv
```

now run it (add as cron line):

```
-bash-4.2$ psql t -c "copy c from '/tmp/$(date --iso-8601).csv';"
COPY 1
```

now check it:

```
-bash-4.2$ psql t
psql (9.3.14)
Type "help" for help.

t=# select * from c;
 i
----
 42
(1 row)
```